# Prevent typing in Text Field Input, Even Though Field is NOT Disabled/Read-Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, disabled-input

Can I prevent HTML Text Field input even when my field is NOT Disabled or Read-only? I have this requirement.

Maybe I can block all inputs via JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsocgph2/)

You can use jQuery for this.. You can do it as below

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**OR**

you can just return false instead of using `preventDefault()`. See the script below

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    return false
});
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsocgph2/1/)

**OR**

A much simplified version without Javascript would be as below. Just change your HTML as below

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return false;"/>
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsocgph2/2/)

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for read-only input, a simple way is to add 'readonly' to the input HTML. For example,

```
<input type="number" readonly>
```

With this, it doesn't interfere with form submission or other event listeners. Input with 'readonly' will still be submitted, but not input with 'disabled'.

For references: https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: Title literally says `NOT Disabled/Read-Only`. No idea why this is upvoted

Comment: Programmatically doing this and setting the `disabled` attribute on the submit button gets the behaviour asked for

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to make the field complete in-intractable.

```
$('input').focus(function(e) {
    $(this).blur();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/up4j39qr/15/

Answer (score 0):

You could return false on `input` event or use `.val('')` to reset the field when everytime user try to write something :

```
$('input').input(function(e) {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$('input').on('input', function(e) {
    $(this).val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works just fine for me, but I also wanted to include *Shift*, *Esc*, and *delete* keys. In this case use `keydown` instead of `keypress`:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/